# Does visual studio show virtual or physical address while debugging?

Tags: debugging, memory, virtual

[Image demonstrating the memory window while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxHMM.png) 
When using the memory window in visual studio, do we see the virtual address of that process or the physical address of RAM?

Answer (score 2):

User-level code *always* sees **virtual** addresses. It has no way to know what physical address *(if any!)* presently corresponds to one of these addresses. "Virtual" is the only world that it lives in, and the only one that it ever knows. For all of a program's intents and purposes, "virtual *is* reality."

Comment: I have shared the image in the link within question . Can you just have a view over that and elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: *all* operating systems (except MS-DOS and the like ...) run user programs in a *virtual* memory space.  Each program has its own perception of what "location `$12345678` contains," and each program's perception is, *for it,* correct. Each program can have a different number there, and can change it at its own pleasure.

They can do this because *none* of them actually know:

- Where, in *physical* memory, "*their* 'location `$12345678`'" actually resides. *(**If** it does ... and quite-possibly it doesn't!)*
- What is in *physical* address `$12345678`.

The operating system maintains *virtual* memory for each process, using a combination of physical-RAM and *(if necessary)* page-file and/or swap-file space. Information that is actively being used by a process is made available to it "on demand," at a physical RAM-location that is both unknown to it and unknow*able* by it. Information that has not recently been used is eventually "stolen" from physical RAM and moved to external storage ... until it is referenced again, triggering what is known as a "page fault."

The memory view that is given to you by a debugger is the memory view that is perceived by and that is correct for the program being debugged: *virtual* addresses, in the process's *virtual* memory.

Comment: Is there any maximum limit for the virtual address space of a process? As when we use top command on linux .It shows the physical memory and virtual memory of a process. (which keeps on changing). How can the virtual memory change for a process

Comment: The application program perceives that it has available to it a (virtual) memory area of a certain size. It cannot detect whether a page-fault would result from an attempt to access any particular location. It can pre-determine the size of its (virtual) memory allocation only by making a system-call to request this information from the OS.

Comment: The reason why you see ever-changing values from the `top` command is because it *can* see the activity of the OS's virtual-memory subsystem. It can see how much *physical* resources are currently being spent in support of any process: both the current physical-RAM footprint and the swap/page space used by each. It can see how much RAM the process would *like* to have (its so-called "working set size"), and how much RAM it actually gets. It can see time spent waiting. Processes compete for the physical-RAM resource. The physical situation changes constantly ... every microsecond.